# Update settings table in database

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with the update settings in my Laravel database.
I can use the variable in my application but I want to update the variable change in my database
My Table:
[image]

My Blade view:

```
<form class="new-added-form" action="{{route('update.setting')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                @csrf
                @foreach($settings as $setting)
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-12 form-group p-5" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$setting->id}}" name="set_id"/>
                    <label for="app_name">{{$setting->name}}:*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="{{$setting->key}}" id="app_name" value="{{$setting->value}}">
                    @if($setting->type == 1)
                    <input type="file">
                    <img src="{{asset($setting->value)}}" alt="{{$setting->name}}" width="300">
                    @endif
                    @error('APP_NAME')
                    <span class="badge badge-warning">{{$message}}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                @endforeach
                <div class="col-12 form-group mg-t-8">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn-fill-lg btn-gradient-yellow btn-hover-bluedark">ذخیره</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My Controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    ????
}
```

How do I update a variable in my database?

Answer (score 1):

First, read the section about `Eloquent` in the laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

There you will learn about models and how to use them.
You should create a model that represents your table with all it's fields.

Second: Read the section about `Validation` of requests:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation

After that, you can use them like:

```
public function update(SettingsRequest $request, Settings $settings)
{
    /**
    /*
    /* $settings is your model representing your "settings" table
    /* $request is a formrequest validator, so all values are "safe"
    /*
    **/
    $settings->update($request->save());
    return to_route('home'); // or whatever you like
}
```

So, when using all the tools of laravel, manipulating data in your db is very, very simple ;)

Comment: I created the model.
I am also familiar with storage and validation
But the problem is that this is a configuration table and there is one from each row and I do not want new rows to be created.
Please take a closer look at the codes

Comment: The way you have displayed above, you would end up having n times the field `set_id` (for example). Think about to refactor it to have the names like `setting.3.id` or `settings.2.key`. This way, you can process this is in an update function with a foreach and have all the pros of the request validator and the model ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laravel 9, and using package from spatie: [spatie/laravel-settings](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings).

If you follow the docs you may set the setting class.

In the settings folder, App\Settings will have a new file GeneralSettings.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Settings;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Spatie\LaravelSettings\Settings;

class GeneralSettings extends Settings
{
    public string $site_name;

    public string $site_timezone;

    public static function group(): string
    {
        return 'general';
    }
}
```

In AppSeviceProvider.php we add a new line under the boot method:

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * General settings
         *
         */
        if(DB::table('settings')->where('group', 'general')->exists()) {
            config()->set('app', array_merge(config('app'), [
                'name' => app(GeneralSettings::class)->site_name,
                'timezone' => app(GeneralSettings::class)->site_timezone,
            ]));
        }
    }
```

If you want to save the settings, in controller, you may do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UpdateWebSettingRequest;
use App\Settings\GeneralSettings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class SettingController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(
        protected GeneralSettings $settings
    )
    {

    }

    public function editSetting()
    {
        return view('admin.setting.index');
    }

    public function updateWebSetting(UpdateWebSettingRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $this->settings->site_name = $validated('site_name');
        $this->settings->site_timezone = $validated['site_timezone'];
        $this->settings->save();

        return redirect(route('admin.settings.edit'))->with('success', 'Tetapan web telah berjaya disimpan!');
    }
}
```

If we do not put the `if` statement, it would be an error while want to run php artisan command.

In other cases, you may extend the Illuminate\Foundation\Application class, and you may use something like this app()->getName() in everywhere in your application, but to set the config I'm still using the boot method in AppSeviceProvider.php.

Hope it helps.